# What is this equation mean N(1 <= N <= 100)

Tags: math, notation

I am not so good in math and I have an interview question to answer but I can`t understand this equation:
the interview question is:
write a function that, given an integer  N(1 <= N <= 100) returns array containing N unique integer that sum up to 0.

I cant understand it to solve it please help what N(1 <= N <= 100) this mean.

P.S: I am not looking for ready solution, I want understand the concept so I can solve it my self.
Thanks.

Edit: its not a range from 1,100 as you`re suggesting, here is the question image
[image]

Comment: "Given an integer named N that is between 1 and 100 included..."

Answer (score 0):

It means that both (1 <= N) and (N <= 100).  So N is an integer from 1 to 100.

Answer (score 0):

```
N(1 <= N <= 100)
```

simply means that you have a number `N` that is greater or equal to `1` and smaller or equal to `100`.

In other words, it is an integer from `1` to `100` with both bounds inclusive.

It can also be written like that: `N ∈ [1, 100] ∩ ℤ` or `N ∈ {x ∈ ℤ: 1 ≤ x ≤ 100}`

Comment: Well, typically [1, 100] is the set (an *interval*) of all *real* numbers between 1 and 100, so slightly more accurate would be "N ∈ [1, 100] ∩ ℤ". Also, your second version uses or (∨) but should use and (∧), and its syntax is slightly odd. The vertical bar is typically part of the set-builder notation, but you are missing the set brackets. More standard would be N ∈ {x ∈ ℤ : 1 ≤ x ∧ x ≤ 100}, or, much more natural, N ∈ {x ∈ ℤ: 1 ≤ x ≤ 100}, but this is too verbose. The original version given by the OP is the best one, if only you add the missing space!

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand You are completely right - that's the result of copying the characters from wikipedia on a mobile phone...

Comment: Sorry, but now it got even worse! :( "1<=N ∩ N<=100" doesn't make sense. ∩ is set intersection, so the things next to this symbol must be sets, but they are propositions in this case, so you need the logical and operator ∧.  (But semantically, they are related: {x ∈ X: P(x) ∧ Q(x)} = {x ∈ X: P(x)} ∩ {x ∈ X: Q(x)}.)

Comment: Now, I just copied the expression from you because I didn't want to fight against my mobile :)